# Background Selector in RecyclerView Item

Tags: android, selector, android-recyclerview

I'm using the `RecyclerView` like below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and my list item:

```
<LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_medium_high">
    <com.basf.suvinil.crie.ui.common.widget.CircleView
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="57.5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

see in detail this part `android:background="@drawable/selector_medium_high"` it's a normal selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_high" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_high" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_high" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_high" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_medium"/>
</selector>
```

but when I run this code, i have no changes in background color when I touch the row....

Comment: Unfortunately using focusable views is not a good way to track selection. Check my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Set `clickable`, `focusable`, `focusableInTouchMode` to `true` in all elements of `RecyclerView` "list".

Comment: Today, RecyclerView have no onItemClick. but setting true in clickable, focusable and focussableInTouchMode has solved the issue :)

Comment: I dont know how SO see this kind of answer, but you help-me at all, i think have no problem if you just remove the 2 step and set true instead false in step 1 and it will be ok, the answer is right

Comment: Where is "my_list_view"? I don't see anything called "my_list_view" in this example? Confusing

Comment: He means "list" not "my_list_view"

Comment: why not to use - android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" ?

Comment: I think clickable is enough!

Answer (score 36):

Add :

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

in `item.xml`

Comment: But this produces a ripple effect.

Answer (score 18):

If nothing of this works for you, like it didn't for me, use this code:

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

The trick is in `android:foreground` attribute...

Comment: This would have the adverse effect of overlaying the actual content and can only be used in `FrameLayout` before API 23 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52411921/461982)

Answer (score 15):

Adding `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` to `my_list_item.xml`'s **root layout** seems to work for me (assuming you want the default selection colour).

Also make sure the root layout's `android:layout_width` is `match_parent` rather than `wrap_content` to ensure that the whole row is selectable.

Comment: How can you change the default selection color when using ```android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"```?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately using focusable views to simulate item selection is **not a good solution** because:

- Focus is lost when `notifyDataSetChanged` is called
- Focus is problematic when child views are focusable

I wrote a base adapter class to automatically handle item selection with a RecyclerView. Just derive your adapter from it and use drawable state lists with state_selected, like you would do with a list view.

I have a [Blog Post Here](http://innodroid.com/blog/post/tracking-selected-item-in-recyclerview) about it, but here is the code:

```
public abstract class TrackSelectionAdapter<VH extends TrackSelectionAdapter.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {
    // Start with first item selected
    private int focusedItem = 0;

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        // Handle key up and key down and attempt to move selection
        recyclerView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

                // Return false if scrolled to the bounds and allow focus to move off the list
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
                        return tryMoveSelection(lm, 1);
                    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
                        return tryMoveSelection(lm, -1);
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean tryMoveSelection(RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm, int direction) {
        int tryFocusItem = focusedItem + direction;

        // If still within valid bounds, move the selection, notify to redraw, and scroll
        if (tryFocusItem >= 0 && tryFocusItem < getItemCount()) {
            notifyItemChanged(focusedItem);
            focusedItem = tryFocusItem;
            notifyItemChanged(focusedItem);
            lm.scrollToPosition(focusedItem);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, int i) {
        // Set selected state; use a state list drawable to style the view
        viewHolder.itemView.setSelected(focusedItem == i);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // Handle item click and set the selection
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Redraw the old selection and the new
                    notifyItemChanged(focusedItem);
                    focusedItem = mRecyclerView.getChildPosition(v);
                    notifyItemChanged(focusedItem);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: who is mRecyclerView?

Answer (score 5):

```
    viewHolder.mRlPrince.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                viewHolder.mRlPrince.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8"));
            }if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                viewHolder.mRlPrince.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: but horrible answer for Material Design, since this will break the Ripple effect.

Answer (score 4):

Add this below attribute in your Item "my_list_item.xml"
`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` 
This works for me !

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `android:clickable="true"` in the element xml, and if you have more selectors in some view inside your view, you need to set             `android:duplicateParentState="true"`
 there too. 
Thats works on pre honeycomb apis.

Answer (score 1):

As many others answered the only way is to combine selectors and new Classes to keep track of the selection, but better to delegate this calculation to the Adapter. The library **FlexibleAdapter** keeps track of the selections for you, configuration change is also compatible.

Backgrounds color with ripple can now be done without XML part, but in the code to manage dynamic data.

Finally, you can use lot of features with the same library, selection is a tiny basic feature you can have.

Please have a look at the description, Wiki pages and full working example: https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter

Answer (score 1):

on your design or xml file just place the following lines.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```