# Add buttons dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I want to write my first android app using the Android Studio and getting some problems.

I want to write a quizapp and for each answer I want to add a button. But the count of the answers should not be the same for each answer. Thats why I want to add the buttons dynamically. I saw some sample code where the buttons are added via code.

Is there any way where I DONT have to add each button via code? I'm thinking about a way like in WPF where I have a list with answers in my viewmodel and my xaml is generating the buttons (e.g. ListView with ItemTemplate) automatically.

Thx to MattMatt for answering my question!

Comment: you can add button dynamically
create button object and add to root layout

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-a-button-dynamically-in-android?rq=1

Comment: the question is not clear, explain more about your problem

Comment: Changed my answer to make it more clearly. Like I write some times, I asked for a way without adding any button via code....

Comment: We do not want start your code of zero, try to do your code and then show us your problems please, thanks.

Comment: I don't want you to write me the code i just want to know if there is any way without adding each button via code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Android platform, a [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) is a specific widget that is intended to perform a specific action when clicked. You describe a need for a dynamic number of buttons in a list format, for this you should use a [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), which would allow you to bind data to the number of clickable items.

If you want the appearance of each item in the RecyclerView list to look like a button, you can style the XML row item to look like one by inheriting the style from the built-in Button widget. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392722/background-selector-in-recyclerview-item) asks how to style items with a background to provide Button-like visual states.

Comment: Thanks! And thank you for reading my question to the end. That's exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  //Can also be done in xml by  android:orientation="vertical"

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++ {
        Button btnTag = new Button(this);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btnTag.setText("Button " + (j + 1 + (i * 4));
        btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 4));
        row.addView(btnTag);
    }

    layout.addView(row);
}
```

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-programmatically-generate.html

[Add button to a layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907609/add-button-to-a-layout-programmatically)

[How do I programmatically add buttons into layout one by one in several lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195056/how-do-i-programmatically-add-buttons-into-layout-one-by-one-in-several-lines)

Comment: So there is no way without adding each button via code?